# Arabic character in print but not in Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following rest API string searching, in this test, for "Rabat" (capital of Morocco):

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?q=Rabat&format=json
```

The response indicates that there are ten (10) hits on Rabat, the following is the first hit:

```
{
    "place_id":297830008,
    "licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, 
    ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type":"relation",
    "osm_id":2799215,
    "boundingbox":[
        "33.8956294",
        "34.0378455",
        "-6.9174353",
        "-6.7614635"
    ],
    "lat":"34.022405",
    "lon":"-6.834543",
    "display_name":"Rabat, Rabat Prefecture, Rabat-Salé-Kénitra, Morocco",
    "class":"boundary",
    "type":"administrative",
    "importance":0.7728843792797666,
    "icon":"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png"
},
```

Here all is looking correct with the display name in non arabic.

However, when I process this data and print the "display_name" I get the following:

> Rabat ⵔⴱⴰⵟ الرباط, عمالة الرباط, Rabat-Salé-Kénitra ⵔⴱⴰⵟ-ⵙⵍⴰ-ⵇⵏⵉⵟⵔⴰ الرباط-سلا-القنيطرة, Maroc / ⵍⵎⵖⵔⵉⴱ / المغرب

I want to avoid the arabic characters. I have been trying to understand why the encoding is as it is given that the json do not have arabic characters. I guess it is imbedded in one way or another.

I use newtonsoft json parser and the following class:

```
[Serializable]
public class GetLocationLatAndLon
{
public float lat { get; set; }
public float lon { get; set; }
public string display_name { get; set; }
}

public class GetLocationLatAndLon_Class
{
public float lat;
public float lon;
public string display_name;

public GetLocationLatAndLon_Class
    (
        float lat,
        float lon,
        string display_name
    )
{
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
    this.display_name = display_name;
}
}
```

I tested in postman using "en-US" and got the following result:

```
[
{
    "place_id": 297830008,
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "relation",
    "osm_id": 2799215,
    "boundingbox": [
        "33.8956294",
        "34.0378455",
        "-6.9174353",
        "-6.7614635"
    ],
    "lat": "34.022405",
    "lon": "-6.834543",
    "display_name": "Rabat, Rabat Prefecture, Rabat-Salé-Kénitra, Morocco",
    "class": "boundary",
    "type": "administrative",
    "importance": 0.7728843792797666,
    "icon": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png"
},
{
    "place_id": 298239385,
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "relation",
    "osm_id": 7510565,
    "boundingbox": [
        "35.8614815",
        "35.9076687",
        "14.328144",
        "14.4169898"
    ],
    "lat": "35.8818906",
    "lon": "14.3988213",
    "display_name": "Rabat, Northern Region, Malta",
    "class": "boundary",
    "type": "administrative",
    "importance": 0.5718997160820387,
    "icon": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png"
},
{
    "place_id": 15023490,
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "node",
    "osm_id": 1612906052,
    "boundingbox": [
        "37.6924914",
        "37.7324914",
        "44.668785",
        "44.708785"
    ],
    "lat": "37.7124914",
    "lon": "44.688785",
    "display_name": "Rabat, بخش صومای برادوست, Urumia County, West Azerbaijan Province, Iran",
    "class": "place",
    "type": "village",
    "importance": 0.5098515324297272,
    "icon": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons/poi_place_village.p.20.png"
},
{
    "place_id": 7044218,
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "node",
    "osm_id": 879415793,
    "boundingbox": [
        "36.1692112",
        "36.2492112",
        "45.5142469",
        "45.5942469"
    ],
    "lat": "36.2092112",
    "lon": "45.5542469",
    "display_name": "Rabat, دهستان گورک سردشت, بخش مرکزی, Sardasht County, West Azerbaijan Province, Iran",
    "class": "place",
    "type": "town",
    "importance": 0.4865275868863176,
    "icon": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons/poi_place_town.p.20.png"
},
{
    "place_id": 298679622,
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "relation",
    "osm_id": 7508583,
    "boundingbox": [
        "36.0328322",
        "36.0533278",
        "14.2262377",
        "14.2530749"
    ],
    "lat": "36.0428907",
    "lon": "14.2398479",
    "display_name": "Victoria, Gozo Region, Malta",
    "class": "boundary",
    "type": "administrative",
    "importance": 0.46244574312518677,
    "icon": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png"
},
{
    "place_id": 136943416,
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "way",
    "osm_id": 138576111,
    "boundingbox": [
        "42.0485356",
        "42.0671547",
        "69.514576",
        "69.526892"
    ],
    "lat": "42.058495",
    "lon": "69.524307",
    "display_name": "Rabat, Kazygurt District, Turkistan Region, Kazakhstan",
    "class": "place",
    "type": "hamlet",
    "importance": 0.41840521716649803,
    "icon": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons/poi_place_village.p.20.png"
},
{
    "place_id": 47901516,
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "node",
    "osm_id": 4040362312,
    "boundingbox": [
        "36.029767",
        "36.069767",
        "48.7782709",
        "48.8182709"
    ],
    "lat": "36.049767",
    "lon": "48.7982709",
    "display_name": "Rabat, بخش مرکزی شهرستان خدابنده, Khodabandeh County, Zanjan Province, Iran",
    "class": "place",
    "type": "village",
    "importance": 0.385,
    "icon": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons/poi_place_village.p.20.png"
},
{
    "place_id": 47344990,
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "node",
    "osm_id": 4022073412,
    "boundingbox": [
        "36.4746789",
        "36.5146789",
        "72.4281545",
        "72.4681545"
    ],
    "lat": "36.4946789",
    "lon": "72.4481545",
    "display_name": "Rabat, Upper Chitral District, Former Chitrāl District, Malakand Division, Khyber Pakhtunkhwa, Pakistan",
    "class": "place",
    "type": "village",
    "importance": 0.385,
    "icon": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons/poi_place_village.p.20.png"
},
{
    "place_id": 24448582,
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "node",
    "osm_id": 2634499330,
    "boundingbox": [
        "34.8177076",
        "34.8577076",
        "73.0246197",
        "73.0646197"
    ],
    "lat": "34.8377076",
    "lon": "73.0446197",
    "display_name": "Rabat, Khyber Pakhtunkhwa, Pakistan",
    "class": "place",
    "type": "village",
    "importance": 0.385,
    "icon": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons/poi_place_village.p.20.png"
},
{
    "place_id": 47619517,
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "node",
    "osm_id": 3996667867,
    "boundingbox": [
        "35.5740355",
        "35.6140355",
        "68.5240975",
        "68.5640975"
    ],
    "lat": "35.5940355",
    "lon": "68.5440975",
    "display_name": "Rabat, Dushi, Baghlan Province, Afghanistan",
    "class": "place",
    "type": "village",
    "importance": 0.385,
    "icon": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons/poi_place_village.p.20.png"
}
]
```

I ended up using regex to solve this in the app, dunno yet if I catch all these characters.

```
_result1.Item2[i].display_name = Regex.Replace(_result1.Item2[i].display_name, @"[^0-9a-öA-Ö\._]", " ");
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
        Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);
        _result1.Item2[i].display_name = regex.Replace(_result1.Item2[i].display_name, " ");
        Debug.Log(_result1.Item2[i].display_name);
```

Example of result:

> Rabat, بخش صومای برادوست, Urumia County, West Azerbaijan Province, Iran

vs.

> Rabat Urumia County West Azerbaijan Province Iran

Comment: I used Insomnia to look at this, and the data coming back for the first item is "Rabat ⵔⴱⴰⵟ الرباط, عمالة الرباط, Rabat-Salé-Kénitra ⵔⴱⴰⵟ-ⵙⵍⴰ-ⵇⵏⵉⵟⵔⴰ الرباط-سلا-القنيطرة, Maroc / ⵍⵎⵖⵔⵉⴱ / المغرب". Try it yourself (or try it with Postman) and you should see the same result.

Comment: *However, when I process this data and print the "display_name" I get the following:* -- please share the code that reproduces this problem.  If I go to `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?q=Rabat&format=json` in a browser, a JSON array is returned.  The first entry is `"display_name":"Rabat, باشوية الرباط, Rabat Prefecture, Rabat-Salé-Kénitra, Morocco",`

Comment: I found the return string is based on your culture info (especially the Accept-Language header). When I sent with en-US, it returned same content as your first hit.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `curl` returns a response with Arabic letters (same with and without `accept-language: en-US` header)